# Google Play rejected update but won't let me update description

Tags: android, google-play-console, accessibility

Oh Google.

Earlier today I was prompted in Google Play Console:

> *Some information about your app is incomplete You can’t edit this app until you declare sensitive permissions in App Content Center. Go to
> App content*

So I went to app content and see they wanted me to fill out why I need AccessibilityService. The instructions said how there had to be in-app disclosure, and to submit a video of what that looks like. Did that and submitted it.

A few hours later I get an app rejected status and email:

> *App Status: Rejected Your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to a policy violation. If you submitted an update, the previous
> version of your app is still available on Google Play.*
>
> *Issue: Missing description in Play Listing We were unable to approve your app because the app description on the play store does not
> reflect the use of AccessibilityService API. Please update your app's
> long description so that it meets all the policy requirements.*

Okay, the instructions never said anything about the Play store description. **So I go to edit it and I can't! All the fields are greyed out and the same warning appears on the top:**

> *Some information about your app is incomplete You can’t edit this app until you declare sensitive permissions in App Content Center. Go to
> App content*

If I go to the App Content -> Sensitive Permissions, it's already submitted and there's nothing to change there.

Any idea what I can do? I submitted an appeal but this is so ridiculous :(

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions nothing we can really do here, unfortunately

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's unrelated to programming.

Comment: Yea it's sad I have to come here for this because there's no on to talk to at Google.

Comment: Gotta love Google and their policies which they never tell you how to deal with properly.. Any idea what is expected to be said in the description specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out I had to refresh the page, and then I could make changes. Still a pretty terrible experience. Especially as they don't tell you anything about the store description when submitting the sensitive permission form.